# MySQL/hive query for one result per item in an array

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, hive

I have a list of ids I am interested in selecting data for in hive. For each of these ids, there are one or more entities stored in a table called `books` that have this id in a `global_parent_id` column. I’m wondering if there’s a query I can write where I pass in the list of ids and for each id in the list, get only ONE entry from `books` that has the id as its `global_parent_id`. I was trying this Hive query (will accept MySQL suggestions too), but it only returns one result, whereas I want to return one child book id for each parent book id. Thanks in advance.

```
select distinct(book_id) from books where global_parent_id in (‘23434’, 23425’, ‘22322’) limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`limit 1` will only return 1 record even if multiple rows satisfy the condition. Use `row_number` function in Hive.(Change `order by` in `row_number` depending on your rules)

```
select global_parent_id,child_book_id
from (select global_parent_id,child_book_id,
      row_number() over(partition by global_parent_id order by child_book_id) as rnum
      from books 
      where global_parent_id in ('23434', '23425', '22322')
     ) t
where rnum=1
```

Comment: Won't this only return the cases where there is only one child book that points to the parent ID?

Comment: I'm looking for a query that will return one child book for each parent ID (even if there is more than one child book that points to the parent ID)

Comment: i changed it to `partition by global_parent_id`..i guess that is what you need.

Comment: `t` is just an `alias` for the sub query..it can be anything you want as long as it is not a reserved keyword.